# A question about the extremum of absolute value

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

For all $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$ , how to find the minimum of the function $$f(a,b,c)=\max\{|a+1|,|2a+b|,|b+2c|,|c-2|\}\,? $$

I know that all of them are above $0$, but I don't know how to solve this, since the four values are connected with each other.

Addition:
My teacher gave me a answer, which is from @Siong Thye Goh 's answer.
Call the biggest one $A$,
and trivially $6A \geq 2|a+1|+|2a+b|+|b+2c|+2|c-2| \geq |-2a-2+2a+b-b-2c+2c-4| = 6$
So $A \geq 1$.

Comment: What do you mean "minimum of the biggest one"?  Why can't they each achieve zero?  For example:  (1) a=-1, (2) 2a=-b, (3) (b=-2c) , (4) c=2

Comment: @mjw They can't all **simultaneously** be $0$

Comment: @mjw a,b,c are connected with each other.

Comment: @某个O5 $a,b,c$ are not connected, you can vary them as you like. The four absolute values are connected.

Comment: @jjagmath yes, you're right.

Comment: @Siong Thye Goh I've learned elementary math and some basic college algebra, like commutative algebra and that sort of things:)

Comment: @jjagmath, you are right.  I didn't understand "minimum of biggest one".  This is a minimax problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there is a simpler approach. Hopefully knowing the answer can help you find a better approach.

This is a problem that can be approached by a tool called [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming).

You want to solve

$$\min_{a,b,c} \max(|a+1|, |2a+b|, |b+2c|, |c-2|).$$

This can be rewritten as

$$\min z$$

subject to

\begin{align}z &\ge a+1\\
 z &\ge -a-1 \\
z &\ge 2a+b \\
z &\ge -2a-b\\
z &\ge b+2c\\
z &\ge -b-2c\\
z &\ge c-2\\
z &\ge -c+2 \end{align}

```
from scipy.optimize import linprog

c = [1, 0, 0, 0]
A_ub = [[-1, 1, 0, 0], [-1, -1, 0, 0], [-1, 2, 1, 0], [-1, -2, -1, 0], [-1, 0, 1, 2], [-1, 0, -1, -2], [-1, 0, 0, 1], [-1, 0, 0, -1]]
b_ub = [-1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, -2]
res = linprog(c, A_ub = A_ub, b_ub = b_ub, method = 'simplex')
print(res)
```

The solver found that $z=\frac43, a=\frac13, b = 0, c= \frac23$.

Comment: I think this is the only way to solve it. It's a linear optimization problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my teacher gave me a different answer, for which I will add to my question description. I didn't find any mistakes. May you have a look?

Comment: Your teacher just gave a lower bound, he didn't claim that the bound is tight.

Comment: OK that's right. Thanks again:)

Comment: btw, I rolled back your question because it gives more context and who knows someone might get inspiration from there. Let's hope someone can see a different elegant solution. :)